# E0167 error : C++ argument of type * is incompatible with parameter of type "FILE**"

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

i am very new to C and while working on examples in the book, i keep getting "C++ argument of type * is incompatible with parameter of type **" Error. I am using visual studio 2019 C++. Here is where i get the error when i use fopen_s:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE *inFile;

inFile = fopen_s("prices.dot","r"); /*Here is the line with an error*/

if (inFile == NULL)
{
    printf("\nThis file does not existL");
    printf("\nPlease make sure that this file currently exist");
    exit(1);

}

printf("\nThe file has been succfully open for reading.");

return(0);
}
```

when i use "fopen" i get a warning which tells me to use fopen_s and when i do use fopen_s, i get the other error. I was wondering if i could get any help with this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using C or C++? This code all looks like C.

Comment: `fopen_s` has different signature than `fopen`.

Comment: The arguments to `fopen_s` are not the same as `fopen`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=msvc-160

Comment: I suggest you turn off the warnings that tell you to use the `_s` versions of functions. Those are all Microsoft-specific, so your code is no longer portable.

Comment: `auto res = fopen_s(&inFile, "prices.dot","r")`.

Comment: @Barmar: [`fopen_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) is C11.

Answer (score 1):

If you google "MSDN fopen_s" and read the documentation on the Microsoft Developer Network, you will find that the function prototype is not identical to fopen():

```
errno_t fopen_s(
   FILE** pFile,
   const char *filename,
   const char *mode
);
```

This means your code in that area would change to look like:

```
FILE *inFile;
errno_t errcode;

errcode = fopen_s(&inFile, "prices.dot","r"); 

if (errcode != 0) { /* do error handling, perhaps quit */ }
```

Alternately, you could continue to write old-style C code, and just use "fopen()" and at the top of your file, to shut MSVC compiler up, add the following #define:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Note, fopen_s() was added to the C 2011 standard, and is described in section K.3.5.2.1 -- meaning this is still portable C code on any modern C compiler.

Your book is probably older than 2011, and this function wasn't part of C at that time.

Comment: Thank you all for the Answers and suggestions. Yes, i am using C. I turned off the warning using #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. It worked.